# How to upload .gif file to smartedit in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Why the gif-s right now are not allowed in SmartEdit although the config says the different:

```
public ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPES: string[] = [
    'jpeg',
    'jpg',
    'gif',
    'bmp',
    'tiff',
    'tif',
    'png',
    'svg'
];
```

smartedit shows error message:
"Selected file type is invalid"
However we can easily add .gif files through backoffice.
We use hybris 19.05 version.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug for 1905 Hybris version. If you upgrade it to 2005 version or 2011 it will be fixed, here is the link to their jira for the bug:

https://cxjira.sap.com/browse/ECP-4148

As @Роман Лотоцький [has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65003042/3346298), if you don't want to do the upgrade, you could fix it adding on the angular configuration file type the mime type of gifs to be accepted by smart edit:

"474946383961" is the mime type code of the image uploaded by business team

1. Create a file called myBestextensionMimeType.js in

   `$HYBRIS/hybris/bin/custom/myBestextension/web/features/myBestextensionContainer directory.`
2. Create the Angular module myBestextensionMimeTypeModule in myBestextensionMimeType.js :

   ```
   angular.module('myBestextensionMimeTypeModule', [])
   ```
3. Add media types to your customized extension:

   - Copy the existing mime type codes defined in cmssmartedit to your myBestextensionMimeTypeModule in myBestextensionMimeType.js. The list you define in myBestextensionMimeType.js overrides the existing list defined in seFileMimeTypeServiceConstants constant in cmssmartedit. You copy the list to retain the current values so that you can add to them.
   - Append additional new mime types to the list of values in myBestextensionMimeType.js.

   The following code example from myBestextensionMimeType.js shows the mime type codes copied from cmssmartedit and the new mime types you added to the list:

   ```
   angular.module('myBestextensionMimeTypeModule', [])
   .constant('seFileMimeTypeServiceConstants', {
      VALID_IMAGE_MIME_TYPE_CODES: [
       'FFD8FFDB',
       'FFD8FFE0',
       'FFD8FFE1',
       '474946383761',
       '424D',
       '49492A00',
       '4D4D002A',
       '89504E470D0A1A0A',
       // Insert additional mime type codes here
       '474946383961' // Sample mime type code for GIF89a
   ]
   });
   ```
4. Open the root module of the extension's container and add the newly-created mime type module to `$HYBRIS/hybris/bin/custom/myBestextension/web/features/myBestextensionContainer/myBestextensioncontainerModule.ts` as shown in the example:

   ```
    @SeModule({
     ...
     imports: [
       'smarteditServicesModule',
       'abAnalyticsToolbarItemModule',
       // Import new module here
       'myBestextensionMimeTypeModule',
    ]
    })

    export class MyBestextensionContainer {}
   ```

   The root container is `<custom-extension-name>containerModules.ts`. In our example, the root container is `myBestextensioncontainerModule.ts`.
5. Rebuild your extension:

   ```
   cd $HYBRIS/hybris/bin/custom/myBestextension
   ant build
   ```

Comment: Роман-Лотоцький sorry if I'm late

Answer (score 0):

I added this number 474946383961 to valid image mime types and it helped.

public VALID_IMAGE_MIME_TYPE_CODES: string[] = [
'FFD8FFDB',
'FFD8FFE0',
'FFD8FFE1',
'474946383761',
'474946383961', // gif magic number
'424D',
'49492A00',
'4D4D002A',
'89504E470D0A1A0A',
'3C3F786D6C207665',
'3C73766720786D6C'
];